# H2 varchar column case sensitive

Tags: mysql, h2, case-sensitive

My H2 DB defined with `IGNORECASE=TRUE`. but I need one table column to be VARCHAR case sensitive.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Are you sure that `IGNORECASE=TRUE` doesn't refer to metadata (i.e. column and table names) and not the content of the columns themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VARCHAR_CASESENSITIVE` data type in H2 to override that setting for a column.